# How do I permanently disable manual proxy in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, proxy, http-proxy

I am trying to disable proxy in windows 10. When I disable the manual proxy it just enable itself when I go back to check. How do I permanently disable this? And I am  getting a [127.0.0.1:6061](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J7Th.png) on the address of my proxy please see image

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by:

1. Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key to open Run window.
2. Type "regedit" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the Registry Editor.
3. In the Registry Editor, navigate to the following registry path.

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
   ```
4. Double-click on the ProxySettingsPerUser registry.
5. Change the Value to 1.

This info was taken from [https://www.windowsdigitals.com/disable-proxy-settings-windows-10-permanently/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fbLv.png)